# Regular expression for selection of a range in .net

Tags: c#, .net, regex, c#-4.0

I need to validate the range selection between 0-59 .Here's what I tried which works partially.

```
var a = "0-8";
Regex reg = new Regex("[0-5][0-9]");
if(reg.IsMatch(a))
{
 return true;
}
```

This partially works for input "12-24" but for input "0-8" it fails. what do I need to modify the Regular expression?

Comment: As I often suggest: just write a lexer. It's not hard to write, it's easy to understand, debug and extend, and it lets you write code that gives your user more informative feedback when they make a mistake.

Comment: Try `\b[1-5]?[0-9]\b` instead [demo](https://regex101.com/r/OXbqWt/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect the whole string and not to allow values like `2-ok` or `-11` or `55+56` then use `^([0-5]?[0-9]|60)-([0-5]?[0-9]|60)$` as the regex pattern:

```
var a = "0-8";
Regex reg = new Regex("^([0-5]?[0-9]|60)-([0-5]?[0-9]|60)$");
if(reg.IsMatch(a))
{
    return true;
}
```

It'll return following values for the specified input:

```
var s1 = "0-59"; // true
var s2 = "59-59"; // true
var s3 = "0-60"; // false
var s4 = "0_59"; // false
var s5 = "60-59"; // false
var s6 = "59-0"; // true
var s7 = "0-0"; // true
var s8 = "0-"; // false
var s9 = "-0"; // false
var s10 = "0-80"; // false
```

Comment: The regex which you have given matches for var a = "0-80" which is not correct. Ideally valid scenario should be selection between 0 and 60

Comment: @user1400915 TY for your comment. I fix my regex with line start and end characters `^$`